# Xvfb failed start error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 11.04
I am trying to install Xvfb and CutyCapt in order to take a snapshot of webpage
I followed a instruction  https://github.com/jaequery/cutycapt-installer-script-on-ubuntu/blob/master/install
and I executed last line and it gives me an error

xvfb-run: error:Xvfb failed to start

Any solution for that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `xvfb-run` hides error messages by default... give it a `-e /dev/stdout` to see what the problem is.

Comment: I am getting Server is already active for display 99 If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X99-lock and start again.

Comment: Did you remove the temporary file as the message recommended? What was the result?

Comment: If you want to run multiple processes at the same time, then it is best not to remove the lock file, but use -a option, as described in answers below. This will get the next free server number.

Answer (score 155):

I was getting this error "xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start" on Ubuntu 14.04, where previously my script had run without problems on Ubuntu 12.04.

My scripts were running calling xvfb-run multiple times, but I was seeing fails due to the error "Server is already active for display 99"

It seemed that the Xvfb wasn't ending when the xvfb-run command returned.

My solution was to use `"xvfb-run -a [mycommand]"` so xvfb uses another display if 99 is in use.

Comment: This answer pointed me to the solution. In my case, a previous run of xvfb-run was hung so I found the pid using "ps aux | grep xvfb" and killed the process.

Comment: -a also worked for me using with wkhtmltopdf :) xvfb-run -a /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 32):

Had the same issue, solved it by running this instead:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 [your script]
```

***--auto-servernum*** : Try to get a free server number, starting at 99, or the argument to ***--server-num***

Comment: Is there difference between this and -a?

Comment: Both are the same. Use either -a or --auto-server-num

Answer (score 26):

Run `xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout [mycommand]` as @wumpus suggested.

I received the server lock message:

```
Fatal server error:
Could not create server lock file: /tmp/.X99-lock

xvfb-run: 

error: Xvfb failed to start
```

Using `sudo` resolved the issue for me:

```
sudo xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout [mycommand]
```

Answer (score 19):

Found the problem There is hanging process in system with name

```
Xvfb
```

I killed it and work fine. I newer found it earlier beacuse I used to try to find process with 'xvfb' name

Comment: Yep! A simple `pkill Xvfb` before tunning the command will do!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when running a bash script on Mac OS. Opening XQuartz before running the script solved my problem.