# selenium tests fail: xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start

Tags: php, selenium, ubuntu, xvfb

I have this configuration for selenium testing in phpuni-environment.conf file

```
[program:selenium]
command=xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/usr/bin/firefox -jar /usr/share/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar
autostart=false ; selenium

[program:python-webserver]
command=python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
directory=. ; python-webserver
autostart=false ; python-webserver

[program:php-webserver]
command=php -S localhost:8080
directory=. ; php-webserver
autostart=false ; php-webserver
```

I do the testing via vagrant. Whenever I run any kind of test, I always get this error

```
xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start
```

I found several solutions for this error and I tried this

```
command=xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 java -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/usr/bin/firefox -jar /usr/share/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

but still I get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there maybe already a xvfb-instance running? See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610678/3054219) or [this issue](https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/131).

Answer (score 0):

Below code to start XVFB server and test in headless mode written for java perspective.

should run below command in CENTOS

DISPLAY=:99
sudo java -jar  /root/Seleniumfolder/selenium-server-standalone-2.50.0.jar -log /root/Seleniumfolder/SeleniumServer.log  -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444 -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/usr/bin/firefox"

Comment: could you please give me the documentation for this? I can not find it.