# How to run OpenAI Gym .render() over a server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyglet, xvfb, openai-gym

I am running a python 2.7 script on a p2.xlarge [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) server through Jupyter (Ubuntu 14.04). I would like to be able to render my simulations.

Minimal working example

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
env.render()
```

`env.render()` makes (among other things) the following errors:

```
...
HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 
'apt-get install python-opengl'. If you're running on a server, 
you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work: 
'xvfb-run -s \"-screen 0 1400x900x24\" python <your_script.py>'")
...
NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
```

I would like to some how be able to see the simulations. It would be ideal if I could get it inline, but any display method would be nice.

**Edit**: This is only an issue with some environments, like classic control.

---

**Update I**

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726227/xvfb-failed-start-error) I tried the following, instead of the `xvfb-run -s \"-screen 0 1400x900x24\" python <your_script.py>` (which I couldn't get to work).

```
xvfb-run -a jupyter notebook
```

Running the original script I now get instead

```
GLXInfoException: pyglet requires an X server with GLX
```

---

**Update II**

Issue [#154](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/152) seems relevant. I tried disabling the pop-up, and directly creating the RGB colors

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()

img = env.render(mode='rgb_array', close=True)  
print(type(img)) # <--- <type 'NoneType'>

img = env.render(mode='rgb_array', close=False) # <--- ERROR
print(type(img))
```

I get `ImportError: cannot import name gl_info`.

---

**Update III**

With inspiration from @[Torxed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929999/torxed) I tried creating a video file, and then rendering it (a fully satisfying solution).

Using the code from '[Recording and uploading results](https://gym.openai.com/docs)'

```
import gym

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.monitor.start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1', force=True)
observation = env.reset()
for t in range(100):
#    env.render()
    print(observation)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
        break

env.monitor.close()
```

I tried following your suggestions, but got `ImportError: cannot import name gl_info` from when running `env.monitor.start(...`.

From my understanding the problem is that OpenAI uses `pyglet`, and `pyglet` 'needs' a screen in order to compute the RGB colors of the image that is to be rendered. *It is therefore necessary to trick python to think that there is a monitor connected*

---

**Update IV**

FYI there are solutions online using bumblebee that seem to work. This should work if you have control over the server, but since AWS run in a VM I don't think you can use this.

---

**Update V**

Just if you have this problem, and don't know what to do (like me) the state of most environments are simple enough that you can create your own rendering mechanism. Not very satisfying, but.. you know.

Comment: Have you tried making a virtual screen buffer like the very helpful error message asks?

Comment: That is the thing, I don't know how to do that. In the guides that I have looked at I don't understand how to make it work over the server.

Comment: I have updated the post with my attempt

Comment: I'm stuck here too, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just a heads up, @TokeFaurby, your solution was deprecated as of December 23, 2016. You need to use a slightly different API and a differnet approach to get this working. I think your approach won't work anymore though, since the `VideoRecorder` class as part of `env.wrapper.Monitor` is now calling `env.render` directly.

Comment: I have solved that using this answer: [stackoverflow NameError: name 'base' is not defined, while running open AI gym in GOOGLE COLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250935/nameerror-name-base-is-not-defined-while-running-open-ai-gym-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 45):

Got a simple solution working:

[image: CartPole]

If on a linux server, open jupyter with

```
$ xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" jupyter notebook
```

In Jupyter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from IPython import display
```

After each step

```
def show_state(env, step=0, info=""):
    plt.figure(3)
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    plt.title("%s | Step: %d %s" % (env._spec.id,step, info))
    plt.axis('off')

    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
```

Note: if your environment is not `unwrapped`, pass `env.env` to `show_state`.

Comment: Works well, thanks, but the env still opens in an external window as well (I'm running it local, not in a remote server). Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: I am getting `/bin/xvfb-run: line 181: 0: command not found` and `/bin/xvfb-run: line 186: kill: (31449) - No such process` errors. Any idea?

Comment: What does the "`24`" in `1400x900x24` mean?  I'm guessing `1400` is monitor width and `900` is monitor height

Comment: 24 specifies the bit depth of the virtual monitor - see [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml)

Comment: My problem happens at the render stage: env = gym.make('CartPole-v0') ; env.render(mode='rgb_array') ;  gives me ValueError: Array length must be >= 0, not -48424951659315200

Answer (score 31):

[This](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/56) GitHub issue gave an answer that worked great for me. It's nice because it doesn't require any additional dependencies (I assume you already have `matplotlib`) or configuration of the server.

Just run, e.g.:

```
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('Breakout-v0') # insert your favorite environment
render = lambda : plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
env.reset()
render()
```

Using `mode='rgb_array'` gives you back a `numpy.ndarray` with the RGB values for each position, and `matplotlib`'s `imshow` (or other methods) displays these nicely.

Note that if you're rendering *multiple* times in the same cell, this solution will plot a separate image each time. This is probably not what you want. I'll try to update this if I figure out a good workaround for that.

#### Update to render multiple times in one cell

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell) StackOverflow answer, here's a working snippet (note that there may be more efficient ways to do this with an interactive plot; this way seems a little laggy on my machine):

```
import gym
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(100):
    plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    env.step(action)
```

#### Update to increase efficiency

On my machine, this was about 3x faster. The difference is that instead of calling `imshow` each time we render, we just change the RGB data on the original plot.

```
import gym
from IPython import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
env.reset()
img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array')) # only call this once
for _ in range(100):
    img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array')) # just update the data
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    env.step(action)
```

Comment: Did you actually try and run this over a server? Or did you only test this on your local machine? What you are suggesting is essentially the same as in **Update II**. The problem is that `env.render()` imports `gl_info` behind the scenes, even if the window doesn't open. `mode=rgb_array` doesn't change that

Comment: Ah, I didn't try it on an AWS server; the one I used must have something configured differently such that I don't get the same error. Sorry it didn't help

Comment: @Nathan there's an additional problem with your solution. Some envs seem to have ways of bypassing the window creation while others do not. For example, if you want to try this out, replace `env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')` with `env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')` in your examples and you'll see what I mean. 'Breakout' happens to be an atari game which uses the `atari_py.ALEInterface()` as its renderer and returns an image. see https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py#L113

Answer (score 16):

I think we should just capture renders as video by using OpenAI Gym `wrappers.Monitor`
and then display it within the Notebook.

Example:

## Dependencies

```
!apt install python-opengl
!apt install ffmpeg
!apt install xvfb
!pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay

# Virtual display
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

virtual_display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
virtual_display.start()
```

## Capture as video

```
import gym
from gym import wrappers

env = gym.make("SpaceInvaders-v0")
env = wrappers.Monitor(env, "/tmp/SpaceInvaders-v0")

for episode in range(2):
    observation = env.reset()
    step = 0
    total_reward = 0

    while True:
        step += 1
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward
        if done:
            print("Episode: {0},\tSteps: {1},\tscore: {2}"
                  .format(episode, step, total_reward)
            )
            break
env.close()
```

## Display within Notebook

```
import os
import io
import base64
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def ipython_show_video(path):
    """Show a video at `path` within IPython Notebook
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise NameError("Cannot access: {}".format(path))

    video = io.open(path, 'r+b').read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(video)

    display(HTML(
        data="""
        <video alt="test" controls>
        <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        """.format(encoded.decode('ascii'))
    ))

ipython_show_video("/tmp/SpaceInvaders-v0/openaigym.video.4.10822.video000000.mp4")
```

I hope it helps. ;)

Comment: I get "NameError: Cannot access: /tmp/SpaceInvaders-v0/openaigym.video.4.10822.video000000.mp4" at the end after running everything. Any idea?

Comment: Check the file name under `/tmp/SpaceInvaders-v0`. The name of the video might be different. Alternatively, provide a known folder for `env = wrappers.Monitor(env, "/tmp/SpaceInvaders-v0")`

Comment: This also does not work with classic control such as "CartPole-v0": ValueError: Array length must be >= 0, not -48424951659315200

Comment: I confirm it works with retro import and SpaceInvaders-Atari2600:/nimport retro/n
from gym import wrappers/n
env = retro.make(game="SpaceInvaders-Atari2600")/n
env = wrappers.Monitor(env, "SpaceInvaders-Atari2600")/n
......../n
ipython_show_video("./SpaceInvaders-Atari2600/openaigym.video.0.2383.video000000.mp4")/n

Answer (score 14):

I managed to run and render openai/gym (even with mujoco) remotely on a headless server.

```
# Install and configure X window with virtual screen
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev
# Configure the nvidia-x
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=None --virtual=1280x1024
# Run the virtual screen in the background (:0)
sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &
# We only need to setup the virtual screen once

# Run the program with vitural screen
DISPLAY=:0 <program>

# If you dont want to type `DISPLAY=:0` everytime
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Usage:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ipython2
```

Example:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Ant-v1')
arr = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
print(arr.shape)
# plot or save wherever you want
# plt.imshow(arr) or scipy.misc.imsave('sample.png', arr)
```

Comment: So just to be sure, this also worked for classic control?

Comment: With the classical control like CartPole, you can try "ssh -X username@hostname" and render directly.

Comment: I was getting the error `ContextException: Could not create GL context remote` and none of the other solutions worked for me, but this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

There's also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb) using `pyvirtualdisplay` (an Xvfb wrapper). One thing I like about this solution is you can launch it from inside your script, instead of having to wrap it at launch:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
display.start()
```

Comment: I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this myself. 
Using xvfb as X-server somehow clashes with the Nvidia drivers.
But finally [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/366#issuecomment-251967650) post pointed me into the right direction.
Xvfb works without any problems if you install the Nvidia driver with the `-no-opengl-files` option and CUDA with `--no-opengl-libs` option.
If you know this, it should work. But as it took me quite some time till I figured this out and it seems like I'm not the only one running into problems with xvfb and the nvidia drivers.

I wrote down all necessary steps to set everything up on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [here.](https://davidsanwald.github.io/2016/11/13/building-tensorflow-with-gpu-support.html)

Comment: I followed the guide to the best of my ability, but couldn't get it to work. The only difference is that I didn't build TF from source, but since this problem is unrelated I don't think it matters.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Since the Amazon Deep Learning AMI now contains a Tensor Flow version with GPU support I'd rather recommend starting from there:
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB

But if you'd still want to setup from scratch, please provide some more information about the problems you encountered, so I can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing my other answer here: [Display OpenAI gym in Jupyter notebook only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726475/display-openai-gym-in-jupyter-notebook-only/54149118#54149118)

I made a quick working example here which you could fork: https://kyso.io/eoin/openai-gym-jupyter with two examples of rendering in Jupyter - one as an mp4, and another as a realtime gif.

The .mp4 example is quite simple.

```
import gym
from gym import wrappers

env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
env = wrappers.Monitor(env, "./gym-results", force=True)
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done: break
env.close()
```

Then in a new cell Jupyter cell, or download it from the server onto some place where you can view the video.

```
import io
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML

video = io.open('./gym-results/openaigym.video.%s.video000000.mp4' % env.file_infix, 'r+b').read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(video)
HTML(data='''
    <video width="360" height="auto" alt="test" controls><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" /></video>'''
.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))
```

If your on a server with public access you could run `python -m http.server` in the gym-results folder and just watch the videos there.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and stumbled upon the answers here. Mixing them helped me to solve the problem.

Here's a step by step solution:

Install the following:

```
apt-get install -y python-opengl xvfb
```

Start your jupyter notebook via the following command:

```
xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" jupyter notebook
```

Inside the notebook:

```
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0') # insert your favorite environment
env.reset()
plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array')
```

Now you can put the same thing in a loop to render it multiple times.

```
from IPython import display

for _ in range(100):
    plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    env.step(action)
```

Hope this works for anyone else still facing an issue. Thanks to [Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45179251/11073592) and [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426542/11073592) for their answers.

Comment: This solution finally worked for me, but I got an error `AttributeError: 'ImageData' object has no attribute 'data'` and installing `pyglet-v1.3.2` fixed that for me from the solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946417/getting-attributeerror-imagedata-object-has-no-attribute-data-in-headle).

Answer (score 2):

I avoided the issues with using matplotlib by simply using PIL, Python Image Library:

```
import gym, PIL
env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
array = env.reset()
PIL.Image.fromarray(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
```

I found that I didn't need to set the XV frame buffer.

Comment: I highly doubt that this works over a headless server. The problem is with the `env.render` function, PIL has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you used `SpaceInvaders-v0`. This issue is only caused by some environment, like classic control. I edited the OP appropriately

Comment: Yes, I see now that my answer only works with some simulations. That's a shame, and limitation of gym.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution that works in Colaboratory and ended up with this

```
from IPython import display
import numpy as np
import time

import gym
env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
env.reset()

import PIL.Image
import io


def showarray(a, fmt='png'):
    a = np.uint8(a)
    f = io.BytesIO()
    ima = PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    return f.getvalue()

imagehandle = display.display(display.Image(data=showarray(env.render(mode='rgb_array')), width=450), display_id='gymscr')

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
    display.update_display(display.Image(data=showarray(env.render(mode='rgb_array')), width=450), display_id='gymscr')
```

**EDIT 1:**

You could use xvfbwrapper for the Cartpole environment.

```
from IPython import display
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
import numpy as np
import time
import pyglet
import gym
import PIL.Image
import io    

vdisplay = Xvfb(width=1280, height=740)
vdisplay.start()

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()

def showarray(a, fmt='png'):
    a = np.uint8(a)
    f = io.BytesIO()
    ima = PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    return f.getvalue()

imagehandle = display.display(display.Image(data=showarray(env.render(mode='rgb_array')), width=450), display_id='gymscr')


for _ in range(1000):
  time.sleep(0.01)
  observation, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
  display.update_display(display.Image(data=showarray(env.render(mode='rgb_array')), width=450), display_id='gymscr')


vdisplay.stop()
```

If you're working with standard Jupyter, there's a better solution though. You can use the CommManager to send messages with updated Data URLs to your HTML output.

[IPython Inline Screen Example](https://github.com/martinenzinger/ipynbs/blob/master/util/InlineScr.ipynb)

In Colab the CommManager is not available. The more restrictive output module has a method called eval_js() which seems to be kind of slow.

Comment: It works with `SpaceInvaders-v0`, but when I call `CartPole-v0` or `Pendulum-v0` I get `NameError: name 'base' is not defined`. Any idea?

Comment: @AfshinOroojlooy try to `!apt-get install python-pyglet && pip install pyglet` and then restart the runtime

Comment: @shadi, thanks for the reply. I solved this problem a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I_like_foxes solution to reinstall nvidia drivers with no opengl fixed things. Here are the commands I used for Ubuntu 16.04 and GTX 1080ti
https://gist.github.com/8enmann/931ec2a9dc45fde871d2139a7d1f2d78

Answer (score 1):

This might be a complete workaround, but I used a docker image with a desktop environment, and it works great. The docker image is at https://hub.docker.com/r/dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc/

The command to run is

```
docker run -p 6080:80 dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
```

Then browse http://127.0.0.1:6080/ to access the Ubuntu desktop.

Below are a gif showing it the Mario bros gym environment running and being rendered. As you can see, it is fairly responsive and smooth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created this [mini-package](https://github.com/dhruvramani/gym-render-browser) which allows you to render your environment onto a browser by just adding one line to your code.

Put your code in a function and replace your normal `env.render()` with `yield env.render(mode='rgb_array')`. Encapsulate this function with the `render_browser` decorator.

```py
import gym
from render_browser import render_browser

@render_browser
def test_policy(policy):
    # Your function/code here.
    env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
    obs = env.reset()

    while True:
        yield env.render(mode='rgb_array')
        # ... run policy ...
        obs, rew, _, _ = env.step(action)

test_policy(policy)
```

When you visit `your_ip:5000` on your browser, `test_policy()` will be called and you'll be able to see the rendered environment on your browser window.

[image]

Comment: Your library doesn't work. When I opened the browser, I couldn't see the environment there.

Comment: The library not working usually has to do with your env. The render mode `rgb_array` might not be implemented. This is esp the case w/ mujoco based non-gym envs.

Answer (score -1):

In my IPython environment, Andrew Schreiber's solution can't plot image smoothly. The following is my solution:

If on a linux server, open jupyter with

```
$ xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" jupyter notebook
```

In Jupyter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib notebook
from IPython import display
```

Display iteration:

```
done = False
obs = env.reset()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

while not done:
    # action = pi.act(True, obs)[0] # pi means a policy which produces an action, if you have
    # obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action) # do action, if you have
    env_rnd = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
    ax.clear()
    ax.imshow(env_rnd)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: This solution results in `NameError: name 'base' is not defined` for me. Any idea?