# Difficulties with AI-Gym Python graphics in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, openai-gym

I am trying to get AI-Gym demos to display in Jupyter notebooks. I get good results for the Atari demo `Breakout-v0` and a difficult error message for the cart-pole demo `CartPole-v0`. Both work fine outside notebooks. The following are the minimal details:

## WITHOUT JUPYTER

At a console:

```
$ pip install gym[atari] &> /dev/null
$ /anaconda3/bin/python3
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gym
>>> env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
>>> env.reset()
>>> env.render()
```

Result:

[image]

Now, likewise with cart-pole, in a new Python session:

```
$ pip install gym &> /dev/null
$ /anaconda3/bin/python3
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
>>> env.reset()
>>> env.render()
```

The *only* difference to the Python code above is the name of the demo: `CartPole-v0` instead of `Breakout-v0`.

Result:
[image]

## WITH JUPYTER

Following some hints from this SO question: [How to run OpenAI Gym .render() over a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195740/how-to-run-openai-gym-render-over-a-server), I have this for the `Breakout` demo:

[image]

or, in text:

```
import gym
from IPython import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')
env.reset()
img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
display.display(plt.gcf())
display.clear_output(wait=True)
```

Now, for the cart-pole, again with a fresh kernel session and notebook, and with the *only* difference being the name of the demo:

```
import gym
from IPython import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
display.display(plt.gcf())
display.clear_output(wait=True)
```

I get a very long error message complaining that some pyglet class is abstract. The last element of the stack trace is the following:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/base.py in get_screens(self)
     63         :rtype: list of :class:`Screen`
     64         '''
---> 65         raise NotImplementedError('abstract')
     66 
     67     def get_default_screen(self):

NotImplementedError: abstract
```

The entire stack trace is at the bottom for inspection. I read through it but was unable to determine the problem and how to fix it. I'd be grateful for advice.

To summarize,

```
NO JUPYTER:
  Breakout: OK
  CartPole: OK
JUPYTER:
  Breakout: OK
  CartPole: ERROR
```

The entire stack trace is as follows:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-df4d39818fe3> in <module>()
      6 env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
      7 env.reset()
----> 8 img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
      9 img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
     10 display.display(plt.gcf())

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/core.py in render(self, mode, close)
    148             elif mode not in modes:
    149                 raise error.UnsupportedMode('Unsupported rendering mode: {}. (Supported modes for {}: {})'.format(mode, self, modes))
--> 150         return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
    151 
    152     def close(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/core.py in _render(self, mode, close)
    284 
    285     def _render(self, mode='human', close=False):
--> 286         return self.env.render(mode, close)
    287 
    288     def _close(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/core.py in render(self, mode, close)
    148             elif mode not in modes:
    149                 raise error.UnsupportedMode('Unsupported rendering mode: {}. (Supported modes for {}: {})'.format(mode, self, modes))
--> 150         return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
    151 
    152     def close(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py in _render(self, mode, close)
    114         if self.viewer is None:
    115             from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
--> 116             self.viewer = rendering.Viewer(screen_width, screen_height)
    117             l,r,t,b = -cartwidth/2, cartwidth/2, cartheight/2, -cartheight/2
    118             axleoffset =cartheight/4.0

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py in __init__(self, width, height, display)
     49         self.width = width
     50         self.height = height
---> 51         self.window = pyglet.window.Window(width=width, height=height, display=display)
     52         self.window.on_close = self.window_closed_by_user
     53         self.geoms = []

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py in __init__(self, width, height, caption, resizable, style, fullscreen, visible, vsync, display, screen, config, context, mode)
    502 
    503         if not screen:
--> 504             screen = display.get_default_screen()
    505 
    506         if not config:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/base.py in get_default_screen(self)
     71         :rtype: :class:`Screen`
     72         '''
---> 73         return self.get_screens()[0]
     74 
     75     def get_windows(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/base.py in get_screens(self)
     63         :rtype: list of :class:`Screen`
     64         '''
---> 65         raise NotImplementedError('abstract')
     66 
     67     def get_default_screen(self):

NotImplementedError: abstract
```

Comment: Maybe with answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149118/1008577

Comment: 3 years and 3 thousand views later, this question still doesn't have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a `.py` script and the rendering will be done in a new windows. Worked on mac for me!