# Make OpenAI gym Monitor only store a video, but not render in real time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I am training an agent for the Cartpole environment of openAI gym, and storing a video, and then I'm trying to display it (doing this in jupyter notebook).

I start with:

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env = wrappers.Monitor(env, "./gym-results", force=True)
```

Then I do a training loop in the standard way using `env.step(action)`. This causes a video to be stored correctly, but weirdly, it also causes the video to pop-up in realtime (just as in the question [Display OpenAI gym in Jupyter notebook only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52726475/6399645)), even though I'm not calling `env.render()` anywhere. **How do I stop this?**