# Getting " AttributeError: 'ImageData' object has no attribute 'data' " in headless gym jupyter Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, pyglet, openai-gym

I am trying to run gym in headless server and render the same in jupyter. Python version 2.7.

I have started the jupyter using  `xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" jupyter notebook`

Below is the Jupyte cell that I run.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gym
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()

plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
display.display(plt.gcf())    
display.clear_output(wait=True)
env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action

env.close()
```

But the error I get is as below :

```
AttributeError: 'ImageData' object has no attribute 'data'
```

[image]

I have searched a lot in forums but could not find a solution. Thanks in advance to help me fix this error and make me to render gym in jupyter notebook.

Comment: After some time I have chosen to go with Python 3 and used below link for the jupyter setup. And it worked.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue. Installing `pyglet-v1.3.2` instead of `v1.4.1` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! But I did not get that worked even after applying your solution. Still same error. Anyway I am not worried of it as I avoided that issue by switching to python 3.

Comment: @Loganathan I see. Glad you got it!

Comment: I have python 3 and this solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have `python 3.7` and for my upgrading to `gym 0.18.2` solved the problem (with `pyglet 1.5.5`)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, like @patapouf_ai I upgraded from gym 0.9.6 to gym 0.19.0 and this solved the problem. It seems the root issue is that mode=rgb_mode returned error when passed into env.render.